# creating a devtools session with selenium 4 using remotewebdriver

Tags: java, selenium, testcontainers

trying to run with
[webdriver contianer](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/webdriver_containers/) and selenium 4 after creating a devtools session I am getting:

`class org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver`
when running:

```
scenarioContext.setDevTools(((ChromeDriver) scenarioContext.getDriver()).getDevTools());
```

How can I solve this? I need to somehow cast remotewebdriver to chromedriver in order to use devtools.

Comment: can you please add your entire test class and also information which Testcontainers version you are using?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of using DevTools with RemoteWebDriver from official documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/

```
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("<grid-url>"), chromeOptions);
    driver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
    DevTools devTools = ((HasDevTools) driver).getDevTools();
    devTools.createSession();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium 3, ChromeDriver have their own implementation inherited from RemoteWebDriver class. In Selenium 4 ChromeDriver is inherited from ChromiumDriver (which extends RemoteWebDriver). ChromiumDriver class has predefined methods to access the Dev Tools.

Comment: on testconconainers Since browsers are started in a container, they are obviously remote, so a “local” driver cannot be used - how can start a devtools session while my driver object is of RemoteWebDriver type?